# Inject repetitive code into functions: JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function, variables, for-loop, automation

The `add8` function below has a lot of `for` loops inside. I've truncated it for the purposes of this question but there's a good bit more loops in my original function from my source code. Have a look:

```
function select( selector ){
  return document.querySelectorAll( selector );
}

function add8(){
  var x = select( '[ x ]' ), y = select( '[ y ]' ),
    x1 = select( '[ x1 ]' ), y1 = select( '[ y1 ]' ),
    x2 = select( '[ x2 ]' ), y2 = select( '[ y2 ]' ),
    cx = select( '[ cx ]' ), cy = select( '[ cy ]' ),
    i = 0,
    val = 0;

  for( i = 0; i < x.length; i++ ){
    val = x[ i ].getAttribute( 'x' );
    val = Number( val ) + 8;
    x[ i ].setAttribute( 'x', val );
  }  
  for( i = 0; i < y.length; i++ ){
    val = y[ i ].getAttribute( 'y' );
    val = Number( val ) + 8;
    y[ i ].setAttribute( 'y', val );
  }    
  for( i = 0; i < x1.length; i++ ){
    val = x1[ i ].getAttribute( 'x1' );
    val = Number( val ) + 8;
    x1[ i ].setAttribute( 'x1', val );
  }    
  for( i = 0; i < y1.length; i++ ){
    val = y1[ i ].getAttribute( 'y1' );
    val = Number( val ) + 8;
    y1[ i ].setAttribute( 'y1', val );
  }
  // Alot more 'for' loops follow...
}

add8();
```

You might notice that there's only a few values needing to change in these for loops, So I'm desperate for a function that can reuse a lot of the code while making the overall code a lot shorter and concise.

something like

```
function dynamicFunc( dynamicVar, dynamicStr ) {
  for( i = 0; i < dynamicVar.length; i++ ){
    val = dynamicVar[ i ].getAttribute( dynamicStr );
    val = Number( val ) + 8;
    dynamicVar[ i ].setAttribute( dynamicStr, val );
  } 
}

function add8(){
  var x = select( '[ x ]' ), y = select( '[ y ]' ),
    x1 = select( '[ x1 ]' ), y1 = select( '[ y1 ]' ),
    x2 = select( '[ x2 ]' ), y2 = select( '[ y2 ]' ),
    cx = select( '[ cx ]' ), cy = select( '[ cy ]' ),
    i = 0,
    val = 0;

  dynamicFunc( x, 'x' );
  dynamicFunc( y, 'y' );
  dynamicFunc( x1, 'x1' );
  dynamicFunc( y1, 'y1' );

  // Alot more follow...
}

add8();
```

to automate those `for` loops, but the below example does not seem to work. I'm not too great at JS yet and think I need a little help here. How can I do this? Thank you.

*Note: I'm dealing with a lot of SVG's in my source-code, hence the attributes `x`, `y`, `x1` etc... being selected in my JavaScript.*

**Extra Note: I'm using vanilla JS here.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using some ES6 features:

```
function add8(){
  var attributes = ['x', 'y', 'x1', 'y1']; // all the attributes you care about
  attributes.forEach(attribute => {
    [...select(`[${attribute}]`)].forEach(el => {
      el.setAttribute(attribute, Number(el.getAttribute(attribute)) + 8);
    });
  });
}
```

More verbose:

```
function add8(){
  var attributes = ['x', 'y', 'x1', 'y1']; // all the attributes you care about
  var i, j;
  // loop over the attributes:
  for (i = 0; i < attributes.length; i++) {
    var attribute = attributes[i];
    var elements = select('[' + attribute + ']');
    // loop over the selected elements:
    for (j = 0; j < elements.length; j++) {
      var element = elements[i];
      var val = Number(el.getAttribute(attribute)) + 8;
      el.setAttribute(attribute, val);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this example use jQuery? I just saw the `$` and figured I'd ask. Again, not a pro at JS yet, Sorry if it's obvious here.

Comment: @basement no. Nice answer Peter. This is really, really good. I'm super envious of the way you broke that down so quickly into a very small piece of code. My answer was much smaller than the OP, but more than this. As an aside to the OP, this won't work in Internet Explorer, but other than that it seems solid.

Comment: Trying to support atleast all major browsers. @zfrisch you should post your answer if it's better supported. Elegance is great but functionality is first for me.

Comment: @zfrisch no, this is "Vanilla JavaScript". You're right, my first solution is succinct, but quite hard to understand. Take a look at the second solution, which should be equivalent to the first one, but more understandable, and which should work in all major browsers.

Comment: @basement The longer solution should work fine in IE. The major compatibility issue lied within the spread operator `...` and Peter's taken care of that with his more verbose answer.  You should be set!